# How to use correctly \dl with vectors using the diffcoeff package?

Tags: math-mode, macros, diffcoeff

I am showing the following question about the use of differential `\dl` in section six of the user guide [`diffcoeff`](http://mirrors.ctan.org//macros/latex/contrib/diffcoeff/diffcoeff.pdf).

- Why does not the command`\dl \vec{x}` work?
- When dealing with the unknown `x`, the numerical value between `\dl` and `x` indicates the horizontal space of that number in mu before the x. But I do not think that happens in (4) and (5). Is it possible via a command that allows me to use `\dl \vect{x}` in the "natural way"? That is, it works (6).

### Minimal working example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ISO]{diffcoeff}

\begin{document}

\[
    \diff{\vec{x}}{\vec{y}} % (1) Works.
    \qquad
    \vec{\dl x} % (2) Works.
    \quad
    {\vec{}\dl x} % (3) Works.
    \quad
    \dl5\vec{x} % (4) Works.
    \quad
    \dl0\vec{x} % (5) Works.
    \quad
    %\dl \vec{x} % (6) Do not work.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know why, but `\dl \protect\vec{x}` works. Unfortunately, the package `diffcoeff` uses the LaTeX 3 syntax, and I don't know it, so I don't know if there is a better workaround.

Comment: Your discovery is very interesting, that makes me infer that there is a robust command, this can help us to solve, I am going to get the question to the author with the hope that he will give us a help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from an oversight of mine. I didn't think of the `\dl` command being used before commands taking arguments like `\vec{x}` which (obviously) I should have. I have fixed it in version 3.1 of `diffcoeff` (by adjusting the placement of a `\group_end:` command), and will upload to CTAN shortly.

Andrew Parsloe

Comment: I'm glad of the super fast solution and welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: [Here](https://ctan.org/ctan-ann/id/mailman.3152.1552327837.5014.ctan-ann@ctan.org) is the new update of the diffcoeff package!

Answer (score 2):

For reasons that are unknown to me, the `\dl` command absorbs an argument. So your attempt

```
\dl \vec{x}
```

absorbs `\vec` as its argument and chaos ensues.

The implementation of `\dl` is *very* awkward. It comes out that

```
\dl 0 \vec{x}
```

works (spaces are optional).

Are you sure you want to use the package?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this package I discovered a few weeks ago and well, if I send this question to the author, perhaps in the future there is the possibility of using it as we would like in (6). Thank you very much again.

I will mark as a correct answer if it is possible to save with a `\renewcommand` or something similar. The use of this package is with the intention of testing.