# Diffcoeff \dl command with indices

Tags: diffcoeff

I'm trying to typeset a differential form using the diffcoeff package. However, I'm getting errors when trying to typeset variables with indices. Here's a code snippet that doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
\[ \dl{u_{ij}} \]
\end{document}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   u
l.4 \[ \dl{u_{ij}}
                   \]
```

It works when using `\dl0` instead, but this seems to be a workaround. Is this a bug in the package or is there a way to properly typeset this?

Comment: Upgrading to the latest version of the package on CTAN works for me. See e.g. [texlive - Install package from CTAN which is not available in TeX Live - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/424548/install-package-from-ctan-which-is-not-available-in-tex-live)

Comment: Indeed, if I run with TL 2021, the error is as shown, but I get no error with TL 2022 (updated).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I don't have enough privileges to upvote your comments. Is there maybe some workaround for TL2021 users, e.g. some code that I can add to the preamble to fix this?

Comment: You can always copy the package's source code and paste it in your preamble (with sufficient adjustment)... although it isn't much harder to include the package separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the braces around  `u_{ij}`. Omit them and your example compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\begin{document}
\[ \dl u_{ij} \]
\end{document}
```

As others have noted there is a more recent version (v5) of `diffcoeff`. In older versions the code for the differential was an afterthought (and a somewhat embarrassing hack). In version 5 it has been properly integrated into the code.

[Added later] Please note that `\usepackage{diffcoeff}` in the example refers to **v4**. (`\dl{x,y,z}` is possible in v5 but not v4.) I appreciate that it is natural to put braces around multi-token arguments like `u_{ij}` or `\vec{x}` but in v4 that causes problems. `\dl` in v4 swallows the next token or brace group and tests whether it is a digit or a minus sign. Unfortunately the test fails if the brace group itself contains a braced argument, so `\dl {u_{ij}}` fails since `\dl` seizes `u_{ij}` which itself contains a brace group, but `\dl u_{ij}` succeeds because only `u` is seized by `\dl`. For the same reason `\dl {\vec{x}}` fails but `\dl \vec{x}` succeeds.

The problem is that the v4 code for `\dl` uses the conditional `\tl_if_in:NnTF`. If this is changed to `\str_if_in:NnTF` the natural wrapping of braces around multi-token arguments is accepted. (Please feel free to do so if you have access to the code.)

There are many changes in v5 to the v4 user interface. (I proposed giving the new package a different name but was convinced otherwise by CTAN maintainers.) One of the changes is that multi-token arguments to the differential should now (v5) be brace wrapped.

Comment: So, what you're really doing is `\dl{u}_{ij}`?

Comment: @Gaussler The answerer is the package author, so this is intended... that having said I understood that the intention is for `\dl something` to transform the "something" nontrivially *only if* it's nontrivial itself (e.g. `\dl{x, y, z}` anyway, so it should left the argument alone. The implementation _could_ make it so that if it's not brace-wrapped then it should not be absorbed as an argument, but I don't see much difference... (e.g. [math mode - How to use correctly \dl with vectors using the diffcoeff package? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478515/))

Comment: (that having said the current version of the package suggests writing `\dl{\vec{x}}` which is a bit confusing. Maybe write "put the variable in braces, or if there's only a single variable then it's also possible not to"?

Comment: @user202729 I know he is the author, and my comment was a comment to the (in my opinion) slightly strange syntax.